# "question tag after causative verb in the clause"

Tags: tag-questions, causative-have

> ***She had some repairs done, had she not?***

I think that the question tag has been written in the sentence correctly since verb " have " is not used as an auxiliary.

*But I still believe it's just another error in one of my grammar books and, certainly, it can't be a typo.*

Comment: The verb "done" is the action verb in "She had some repairs done" (someone else did the repairs for her) so the correct tag question would be, "She had some repairs done, didn't she?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal usage:

"She had some repairs done, did she not?"

It is, in this form, a proper sentence and is a question.

Comment: We would more naturally say "didn't she?"

Comment: agree that the contraction 'didn't she' would be more common

Answer (score 1):

*She had some repairs done, had she not?*

The 'rule' is this:

If the 'anchor' predicator is an auxiliary, select the same auxiliary, otherwise select "do".

Here, the anchor predicator "had" is not an auxiliary, so the the correct verb in the tag is "do":

*She had some repairs done, didn't she?*